# How do I send data to server by loop without sync problem?

Tags: angular, typescript, synchronization

I have an array of products in typescript (in angular) and I need to update their prices in the database via http calls.

I insert them in such a way:

```
array.foreach(element=>{
   this.product.price=element;
   this.myService.func(this.product).subscribe(a=>{console.log(a);});
})
```

The problem with this code is that the That the final data is incorrect because the answers from the server come slower, so if for example there were 3 objects in the array - then for the last two will send to the server the same price, of the last member of the array.

More clear example:

Assume the array is initialized to these prices:

```
[0]=10
[1]=20
[2]=30
```

Except for that array, I have a product:

```
Product p = new Product('product',50);
```

Now I want to insert to the database 3 more products with the name 'product' and the prices from the array. Thst will be via the function from the server.

The outcome I want is all the products that were inserted to the database

```
product,10
product,20
product,30
```

But instead of this I get this outcome:

```
product,10
product,30
product,30
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Right, I will give an example; It would be more clear

Answer (score -1):

1. The requests are not necessarily ran sequentially, you can use an operator such as concat:

```js
concat(array.map(element=>{
    this.product.price=element;
    return this.myService.func(product)
})).subscribe(a=>{console.log(a);});
```

2. On each iteration you are updating the same instance of the product (if that's not intentional) which has caused strange behavior.

Comment: Thank you Hamidreza Vakilian, but it still doesn't work. The problem happens because of the shared variable  - this.product, that changes to the next value before it is sufficient to reach the server. How can I fix it?